# How do I make the navigation bar span the width of the page and make it be replaced by the button when the screen gets too small?

Tags: html, css

Below is the HTML and CSS used in the problem.
https://jsfiddle.net/64rdv8gp/54/

What I am trying to do is make the nav bar below span the width of the page/screen. Can someone point out to me how to make it span the width of the page. See the link above for a working version of the code.

This is not a duplicate question it's a similar question but due to the code it is different.

Thanks in advance.

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>CSS Only Navigation Menu</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
            <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Register ￬</a>
                <ul class="hidden">
                    <li><a href="#">Drop Down</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Drop Down</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Reviews ￬</a>
                <ul class="hidden">
                    <li><a href="#">Drop Down</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Drop Down</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Drop Down</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
    </html>

           /*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position: absolute;
}
/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
li {
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
/*Style for menu links*/
li a {
    display:block;
    min-width:140px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    background: #00622b;
    text-decoration: none;
}
/*Hover state for top level links*/
li:hover a {
    background: mediumseagreen;
}
/*Style for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    color: #2f3036;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
/*Hover state for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a:hover {
    background: mediumseagreen;
    color: #fff;
}
/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/
li ul {
    display: none;
}
/*Make dropdown links vertical*/
li ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
}
/*Prevent text wrapping*/
li ul li a {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
    display: block;
}
/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/
.show-menu {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #19c589;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: none;
}
/*Hide checkbox*/
input[type=checkbox]{
    display: none;
}
/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu{
    display: block;
}
/*Responsive Styles*/
@media screen and (max-width : 760px){
    /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
    ul {
        position: static;
        display: none;
    }
    /*Create vertical spacing*/
    li {
        margin-bottom: 1px;
    }
    /*Make all menu links full width*/
    ul li, li a {
        width: 100%;
    }
    /*Display 'show menu' link*/
    .show-menu {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the margin-padding from the `body`. - https://jsfiddle.net/kqgcwh1w/

Comment: where is the margin padding in the body?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/64rdv8gp/60/

Comment: That didn't fix the problem, now when you shrink the screen you can see both the button and the nav bar. I would like to see the nav bar at 100% then when the screen is made smaller only the button.

Comment: This question still hasn't been answered...